# Calculate atanh with numbers very close to 1

Tags: python, math, precision

I need to calculate the inverse hyperbolic tangent with great precision. The equation in question is `-atanh(1/ (1 + 10**-x))` where `x` should be on the order of 240 and return the approximate value of -276.65.

I tried some libraries that python provides, like numpy, math and mpmath, however, the largest "x" value I could use was 17. For "x" larger than 17, I get -inf or a domain error.

Comment: could you provide some code?

Comment: Start with defining your function. Do you mean A) Arc-cotangent? i.e. inverse co-tangent, cot^-1, B) Arc-tangent? i.e. atan or tan-1, C) atanh, inverse _hyperbolic_ tangent, which is what your formula uses. Please write it out in full, give one clear example, stating (with a value of x that is reasonable, such as 4), what value you are expecting. Then people will be able to check their understanding of what you are asking.

Comment: When I try `x = 240` and `-atanh(1/ (1 + 10**-x))`, I get an error (`ValueError: math domain error), not `-inf`.

Comment: `10**-240` is *way* smaller than `sys.float_info.epsilon`, which means your denominator is going to be 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_functions.

You have `tanh(x) = sinh(x)/cosh(x)` but `coth(x) = cosh(x)/sinh(x)`. So instead of `artanh(1/(1+ε))` you can write `arcoth(1+ε)`.

Then you can express that using the logarithm. On Wikipedia you find `arcoth(x) = ½ ln((x+1)/(x-1))`. So `arcoth(1+ε)` becomes `½ ln((2+ε)/ε)`.

That is something you can feed into Python. Remembering that you had a negative sign in front of the whole expression you can write it as

```
eps = 10**(-x)  # e.g. eps = 1e-240
res = -0.5 * math.log((2 + eps)/eps)
```

If eps is as small as you indicate, the numerator will round to `2` but the denominator should have enough precision to make the whole thing work. It does for your example: I got `-276.6567847495655` where the correct result would be more like `-276.65678474956545473686759` (computed using `RealIntervalField(1024)` in [Sage](https://sagemath.org) to get guarantees on numeric error) so all the digits we got from double precision arithmetic are pretty much correct.